# How setTimeout works?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a concern with setTimeout function in javascript. when we call setTimeout function without return anything, it is okay for me. like

```
setTimeout(function() {
   console.log("ok function called")
},2000);
```

here in the above example it just simply call that function after 2000ms,

And if I write this like

```
setTimeout(function(params) {
   console.log("passed value is"+params)
},2000,55);
```

now it will call this function with 55 as an argument, right?

But problem is that when I call to write this like

```
setTimeout(function(params) {
   console.log("passed value is"+params)
}(55),2000);
```

here function is calling with 55 as params but it is now waiting for 2000ms

And when I wrote like

```
setTimeout(function(params) {
    console.log("passed value is "+params);
     return function(){
      console.log(params)
     };
 }(55),2000);
```

in this only return function is calling with 2000ms delay, the line console.log("passed value is "+params); is executing instantly

please help me get out of this problem.

Comment: `But problem is that when I call to write this like` - don't do that if that isn't right - but in fact, that code is executed immediately, and after 2000ms ... nothing, because you haven't passed a function to setTimeout

Comment: you seem to be calling it correctly in your second bit of code ... why are you insisting on writing it like the other wrong code - it's wrong - you know it's wrong - so don't do it

Comment: What is your intention in trying to write like that ?

Comment: @Kailash Choudhary after your 3rd code snippet, you mentioned, "here function is calling with 55 as params but it is now waiting for 2000ms" which is wrong, can you validate it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is a function. Another is a function call.

First, let's forget javascript for now. If you know any other programming language, what do you expect the two pieces of code below to do?

```
function a () { return 1 }

x = a;
y = a();
```

What do you expect `x` to be? `1` or a pointer to function `a`?

What do you expect `y` to be? `1` or a pointer to function `a`?

A function is not a function call. When you call a function it returns a value.

---

Now let's switch back to javascript. Whenever I get confused by a piece of code, I try to make the syntax simpler so that I can understand what's going on:

```
setTimeout(function() {console.log("ok function called")}, 2000);
```

Now, that's a compact piece of code, let's make the syntax simpler. The above code is the same as:

```
var a = function() {console.log("ok function called")};
setTimeout(a, 2000);
```

So what does that do? It will call the function `a` after 2 seconds.

Now let's take a look at:

```
setTimeout(function() {console.log("ok function called")}(), 2000);
                                  // Note this ----------^^
```

That's the same as:

```
 var b = function() {console.log("ok function called")}();
 setTimeout(b, 2000);
```

which can further be simplified to:

```
var a = function() {console.log("ok function called")};
var b = a();
setTimeout(b, 2000);
```

So I hope you see what you're really passing to setTimeout. You're passing the return value of the function, not the function.

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
setTimeout(function (params) { return something; }(55), 2000);
```

what actually happens is something like this:

```
var _temp_func = function (params) { return something; };
var _temp = _temp_func(55);
setTimeout(_temp, 2000);
```

The anonymous function you have as a parameter to `setTimeout` is evaluated immediately, even before the call to `setTimeout` itself. In contrast to that, the actual parameter that ends up in `_temp` here is called with a delay. This is what happens in your last example.

Comment: if there is no function in setTimeout as first parameter, setTimeout will print the value immediately.

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn't print anything by itself. Its return-value is an integer that allows you to cancel the timeout, if you meant that.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout takes only function name without parenthesis.
correct syntax : setTimeout(Helloworld) - here you are setting function
incorrect syntax : setTimeout(HelloWorld()) - here you are calling function

or non IIFE function.
It's an IIFE that you are passing hence it is getting called immediately.
setTimeout(function (params) { return something; }(55), 2000);